# Using variables in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to use a flow variable in my Power Automate script.  Power Automate treats the flow variable reference as a literal and does not resolve the variable's value.

```
SET sample TO $fx'"hello this is a test of a string"'
SET NewVar2 TO $fx'"Hello %sample%"'
```

The value of NewVar2 is: `Hello %sample%`

I am trying to achieve in NewVar2 is:

> Hello hello this is a test of a string

I have tried:  `Hello + %sample%, Hello '%sample%', Hello "%sample%", Hello "'%sample%'"` with similar results

Here is what it looks like in the desktop:

[image: example]